# Compute inner product $\langle (1+i,4) , (2-3i, 4+5i) \rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Compute inner product $\langle (1+i,4) , (2-3i, 4+5i) \rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$

- My Answer:

$= (1+i)(2-3i) + 4(4+5i)$

- Book's answer:

$=(1+i)(2+3i)+4(4-5i)$

Why does the book's method conjugate the terms in the second argument of the inner product?

I didn't know we conjugated when directly computing the standard inner product over a complex field. I thought we only conjugate when pulling out a scalar from the second argument or when we swap the order of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There are books that define: $$\langle z,w\rangle_1 = \sum_{j=1}^nz_j\overline{w_j},$$ while others define $$\langle z,w \rangle_2 = \sum_{j=1}^n\overline{z_j}w_j,$$so you have to pay attention to that. If we don't conjugate one of the terms, we won't have the property $\langle z,w\rangle = \overline{\langle w,z\rangle}$ we want. Both are called the standard inner products in $\Bbb C^n$. I numbered them so we can compare: $$\langle (1+i,4),(2-3i,4+5i)\rangle_1 = (1+i)(2+3i)+4(4-5i) \\ \langle (1+i,4),(2-3i,4+5i)\rangle_2 = (1-i)(2-3i)+4(4+5i)$$

You forgot to take conjugates there. Your book is using $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$.

Comment: How are they allowed to use different definitions for a standard inner product when they produce different answers? Also, how am I supposed to tell which one is used - do I look for the subscript?

Comment: Nevermind, I get it! Thank you!

Comment: They won't use any subcript. I put them here for the sake of the answer. The point is that we can have a lot of possible inner products for a single space. In some point of the book, they'll have to explictly give you the expression, at least once.

Comment: They still produce different answers. How is this acceptable?

Comment: They produce different answers because they are different inner products. .. The moral of the story is: pick one of them and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$\langle a, b\rangle = \sum_i a_i\overline{b_i}$
(or
$\langle a, b\rangle = \sum_i \overline{a_i}b_i$
depending on the day of the week)
so that
$\langle a, a\rangle = \|a\|^2$.

Comment: Protip: using `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` produces better symbols. The same goes for `\overline{}` instead of `\bar{}` :)

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Now all I have to do is remember these. With $\LaTeX$, I'm happy if the results are even close to what I want.